# why my table dont have row lines?

Tags: html, css

I face a problem here in my code. I'm newbie in the html and css so the problem is that my `table` do not show any line between my rows when I open in the browser.

You can see the result here:

[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/ibyreb.png]

Here is part of my code:

```
<table class="table" border="1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;;border:1px solid #000000;color:#000000;width:90%;" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3">
    <th bgcolor="#545454">Header1</th>
    <th bgcolor="#545454">Header2</th>
    <th bgcolor="#545454">Header3</th>
    <th bgcolor="#545454">Header4</th>

    <tr>  
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
        <td bgcolor="#D1D1D1">Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.table{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    color:#000000;width:90%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Style your td tag

```
td
{
border:solid 1px #000;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Hoep this helps

Answer (score 1):

you only styled the .table.
try styling the td to.
fe

```
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

also you styled each other row with a background color. you can also do this in your css file, instead of inline

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  bgcolor="#D1D1D1"
}
```